# Why use functions that just return a constant instead of just using a constant?

Tags: c, function, constants

I ran into some code on GitHub. https://github.com/codeplea/tinyexpr/blob/master/tinyexpr.c

These lines caught my eye:

```
static double pi(void) {return 3.14159265358979323846;}
static double e(void) {return 2.71828182845904523536;}
```

Is there any reason at all to use functions in this case? Why not use constants? You could use preprocessor macros, but that can make debugging harder. I have never seen this before. Is there any benefit of this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main reason I can think of is to make it easier to search for where that constant is used.  For example, you search for `e(` instead of `e`.

That isn't the case here, however.  The functions *are* being used, but not called explicitly.

The linked code contains an array of structs:

```
typedef struct te_variable {
    const char *name;
    const void *address;
    int type;
    void *context;
} te_variable;

...

static const te_variable functions[] = {
    /* must be in alphabetical order */
    {"abs", fabs,     TE_FUNCTION1 | TE_FLAG_PURE, 0},
    {"acos", acos,    TE_FUNCTION1 | TE_FLAG_PURE, 0},
    {"asin", asin,    TE_FUNCTION1 | TE_FLAG_PURE, 0},
    {"atan", atan,    TE_FUNCTION1 | TE_FLAG_PURE, 0},
    {"atan2", atan2,  TE_FUNCTION2 | TE_FLAG_PURE, 0},
    {"ceil", ceil,    TE_FUNCTION1 | TE_FLAG_PURE, 0},
    {"cos", cos,      TE_FUNCTION1 | TE_FLAG_PURE, 0},
    {"cosh", cosh,    TE_FUNCTION1 | TE_FLAG_PURE, 0},
    {"e", e,          TE_FUNCTION0 | TE_FLAG_PURE, 0},
    {"exp", exp,      TE_FUNCTION1 | TE_FLAG_PURE, 0},
    {"fac", fac,      TE_FUNCTION1 | TE_FLAG_PURE, 0},
    {"floor", floor,  TE_FUNCTION1 | TE_FLAG_PURE, 0},
    {"ln", log,       TE_FUNCTION1 | TE_FLAG_PURE, 0},
#ifdef TE_NAT_LOG
    {"log", log,      TE_FUNCTION1 | TE_FLAG_PURE, 0},
#else
    {"log", log10,    TE_FUNCTION1 | TE_FLAG_PURE, 0},
#endif
    {"log10", log10,  TE_FUNCTION1 | TE_FLAG_PURE, 0},
    {"ncr", ncr,      TE_FUNCTION2 | TE_FLAG_PURE, 0},
    {"npr", npr,      TE_FUNCTION2 | TE_FLAG_PURE, 0},
    {"pi", pi,        TE_FUNCTION0 | TE_FLAG_PURE, 0},
    {"pow", pow,      TE_FUNCTION2 | TE_FLAG_PURE, 0},
    {"sin", sin,      TE_FUNCTION1 | TE_FLAG_PURE, 0},
    {"sinh", sinh,    TE_FUNCTION1 | TE_FLAG_PURE, 0},
    {"sqrt", sqrt,    TE_FUNCTION1 | TE_FLAG_PURE, 0},
    {"tan", tan,      TE_FUNCTION1 | TE_FLAG_PURE, 0},
    {"tanh", tanh,    TE_FUNCTION1 | TE_FLAG_PURE, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0}
};
```

The second member of each struct is a function pointer used to run some math related function, and the values of E and PI are among them.  So it looks like they were defined as functions to conform to this framework.

Comment: That searching aspect was actually pretty smart.

Comment: it's not that smart. It's better to enable the "whole word only" while searching for e instead of using `e(`. Alternatively use `\be\b` in regex search